# Invalid Project in console after moving solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, project

Our solution file was in a project folder, so I did a saveas and moved it up to the main folder. Now, when we run against the devenv via console commands we get `Invalid project`. But, only for 2010 and not 2012. Some developers are using 2010 and others using 2012, so we need to be able to support both. I cannot seem to find anything on this error, and it is especially odd because the only change I made was to the solution file.

**UPDATE**

OK, this is odd...I just found that I do not get the error if I run devenv from the same directory as the sln. However, I need to be able to run it from another directory using `..\SLN`

Comment: Have you tried manually editing the solution file (in notepad) and ensuring that all the projects in the solution have the correct file path?

Comment: @JeremiahDotNet I figured it out. Horrible error message for a cannot find project...

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to close as too specific, however I think this could be useful to others down the road. The problem is that when the solution was in a nested folder, then doing the following was fine:

```
devenv ..\sln /project ..\projfolder\proj
```

However, when I moved the solution I only changed the solution path

```
devenv sln /project ..\projfolder\proj
```

But, the project path is relative to the solution, not my current executing path. So, I changed the command to the following and it worked:

```
devenv sln /project projfolder\proj
```